# when using build_runner, it showing error with undefined name BuiltList

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-redux, built-value

Currently, I'm doing nested `JsonDeserialize` using `built_value` and `build_runner`. It showing error on generated `serailize.g.dart`. How do i solve this kind of issue?. I also put it `built_collection` in `pubspec.yaml`

[image: this is generated file]

It fine for original file.

[image]

My usage is to parse JSON like this.

```
[
  {
    "id": "some-id",
    "urls": {
      "small": "some-url"
    },
    "user": {
      "username": "some-username"
    }
  },
  //more object comming
]
```

That' why, i prepared my **Dart Model class** to Following

[image]

```
photo.dart
```

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, did you add the following to `serializers.dart`: `import 'package:built_collection/built_collection.dart';`? For future posts, it is a better approach to add code as snippets rather than images. And, for this case it would have been nice to se which files you are importing as well.

Comment: Ohh. Thanks. I'll update